# Unity: How to calculate scrollbar value needed to move the content with known value?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, scrollbar

I have a dynamic way to increase content size depending on number of elements on it.
As the content increases, scrollbar size decreases and the value of scrollbar value needed to move the content by fixed number (100 to right for example) changes also (decreased).
Can I have a method that scroll the content by a fixed number without depending on scrollbar size and value (or an equation that can get the value needed each time)?

Edit:
I know how to scroll by changing Scrollbar.Value (from 0 to 1). But I need to scroll by a fixed number (ex: 100) not a ratio (0-1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll Rect manual scrolling through script Unity C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931773/scroll-rect-manual-scrolling-through-script-unity-c-sharp)

Comment: It is not the same thing. I know how to scroll by changing Scrollbar.Value (from 0 to 1). But I need to scroll by a fixed number (ex: 100) not a ratio (0-1)

Answer (score 1):

`Scrollbar` is just a control which is there for the user to scroll and behind the scene it manipulates `ScrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition` and `ScrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition`.

You don't use `scrollbar` if you have to set the value manually using code. You directly deal with scrollrect's normalized position (which is ranged 0-1).

You can change this value proportionally by calculating the total size of `ScrollRect` and then finding the ratio of your desired scroll value. Something like this:

```
float totalWidth = // find total width of scroll rect transform.
float targetValue = 100;
float targetPercentage = targetValue/totalWidth;

scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = targetPercentage;
```

Now if your `scrollrect` is `500` and you want to scroll to `100`.

your target percentage will be `100/500 (= 0.2f)`

I hope you can figure out the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
1- scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition and scrollbar.value are giving me the same result.
2- Your solution was working but it has 2 problems: *total width is the width of content and not scroll rect because I am changing size of content not scrollrect/ * the target percentage is not giving me the wanted value.
3- While I am trying your solution I figure out a simplest solution by changing the x position of Content transform by the required value (add or subtracting 100)

Comment: Obviously! If your target is content then you can try calculating content-rect size. And as I said, scroll-rect's normalized position is the best way to go because it changes the position of content behind the scene after all.

Comment: The only thing that makes the solution is not working perfectly is the ratio.
May be there is another way to calculate it.

Comment: If your content is not starting from the top/left side of scrollrect then you have to consider offsets as well. I could help more if I could see the actual UI setup you are dealing with :)

Comment: It is at middle-center, you should change to top left corner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161121/discussion-between-bilal1409-and-umair-m).